# django-filter no exception message supplied

Tags: django, django-filter

when i try to use my django-filter MultipleChoiceFilter I get a 'No exception message supplied'
But my other filter works fine, anyone has any idea why?

my filter.py:

```
choices = (('white','white'),('red','red'))

class filtering(django_filters.FilterSet):

   title = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name='title',lookup_expr='icontains')
   color = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(choices=choices)


   class Meta:
       model = Cars
       fields = ['title','color']
```

Comment: Can you show other filter also?

Comment: by other filter i meant the title filter that is shown above, that works fine but when i try to filter on the color i get that error